# How to change popular term checklist title when edit post?

Tags: customization, custom-field, wp-admin

I have a title_custom field in the article category. How can I show that field in place of the title in the category selection box when editing or adding posts?
It's in the function wp_popular_terms_checklist ()
Someone have anyway?
Thanks very much!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the category name. Really, I don't understand what you mean?

For Vietnamese: Hỏi trên này để có câu trả lời là lâu lắm. Tham gia nhóm WordPress Việt Nam mà hỏi, có khi còn nhanh có đáp án hơn ở trên này.

Link group: [WordPress Việt Nam](https://www.facebook.com/groups/wordpressviet)